# How to increase heap memory in docker container?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently try this:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -m 1200M -e JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xmx4000M' selenium/standalone-chrome
```

I don't think it's working since I keep getting a heap memory error. While I haven't directly queried what is the current heap memory allocated to the container, I noticed that the container dies pretty much at the same point regardless of how I change the memory values.

Therefore I am assuming I am not actually changing the heap memory limit?

Answer (score 0):

According to Selenium docker documentation, you should pass JAVA_OPTS (not JAVA_OPTIONS)

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/4b062e7c810ad40deea211f805976d87e56ae7b1/README.md

This should work:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -m 1200M -e JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx4000M' selenium/standalone-chrome
```